# AWS DotNet Core credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk-net

I have an existing dotnet core web application that I need to use a profile other than [default] when I'm developing locally.

I'm running into an issue in that the location of credential file appears to not be defaulted yet to ~/.aws/credentials.  Based on the [credential lookup sequence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/creds-assign.html) check 2 should work if I set the value of `AWSConfigs.AWSProfileName` before creating the SSM Client but it doesn't and just falls through the remaining flow and throws an error saying it can't find the EC2 Meta Data.  The same is the case for check 3.  When the credentials are in the [default] definition check 4 will succeed which I expected would fail as well if defaults haven't been initialized yet. I have multiple AWS accounts that I get temporary security tokens from an SSO system based on the config file and because of temporary token requirement I can't use the [default] profile as I need to be able to switch between them to run the same code base.

I've been able to get around this by explicitly accessing the credential store and generating a set of credentials to pass into the constructor for the SSM Client.

```cs
Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfile developerProfile;
AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient ssmClient;
if (new Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.SharedCredentialsFile().TryGetProfile(Configuration["AWS:Profile"], out developerProfile)) //Test to determine if we have local credentials file with a profile
{
     AWSCredentials credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.SessionAWSCredentials(developerProfile.Options.AccessKey, developerProfile.Options.SecretKey, developerProfile.Options.Token);
     ssmClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(credentials, developerProfile.Region);
}
else
{
     ssmClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(Region);
}
```

The above snippet is designed to allow for running locally with a specific profile and file location and when either do not exist assumes that it's running in an EC2 or ECS environment and can source the credentials from the metadata.

The location of the code that needs access AWS' Parameter Store in located in the `Startup` method so other properties can be initialized before the `ConfigureServices` method is run.  I have additional AWS services that I initialize a client for that work as expected after the `ConfigureServices` has run.  Should I not expect the credential provider to be properly initialized before the `ConfigureServices` method is run?